# Authenticating a user's identity using date of birth

Tags: django, authentication, security

I have a question regarding my implementation of an authentication system based on date of birth. I am using Django, but I think this question can be generalized.

The use case is that the server already knows two things about the user, without them having made an account: a code uniquely assigned to them, and their date of birth. I want to use the combination of these things to authenticate their identity and display sensitive information that belongs specifically to them.

I am trying to understand the best way to do this. Since the user will not be using this website very often, I do not want them to create an account.

Currently my thought process is: user opens webpage with the unique token in the url and enters date of birth. Server validates the token and date of birth and informs the client. On subsequent requests to the server, include date of birth as a header or data field, and perform the same validation on the back-end.

Would this work? Are there superior implementation patterns?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look into [Django Sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/sessions/) and store these information there.

Another way might be to use a custom user model with the token as username and the birth date as password.

Comment: Thanks, I think you've set me down the right path with Django Sessions. To clarify on your suggestion, do you mean once the user has verified their date of birth, to store the date of birth in the session like this: `request.session['dob'] = date_of_birth`, and `request.session['token'] = token`? And then on subsequent requests, ensure these values are present in the session? Would I need to validate them on each subsequent request, or just ensure they exist? I suppose I could also do `request.session['is_authenticated'] = True` in the session data?

Comment: birthdate as a password is not the way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little bit confused about your requirement explanation.
`without them having made an account`
If you don't want the user to register then how server validates user data?
but to do authenticate an user with a username and birth date instead password you can simply create a custom authentication backend.
refer [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#customizing-authentication-in-django)

Comment: Imagine an application where a teacher posts test scores for students. In order for a student to view their score, they are provided a unique code, and must enter their birthday. In this scenario, the teacher is the one with the account, and the teacher registers the students birthday and generates a unique code which is then given to the student in order for them to access their score.

Comment: so unique code is/can be assumed basically be a password. you can add bday in the authentication backend as well. it's possible in another way you can create a normal function that takes those inputs and on AJAX call you can verify it and return desired results and just add/manipulate dom in whichever you like. @colioli

Comment: Wouldn't this require me to add all the fields of `Student` to my `User` model? I am hesitant to consolidate all of the data into a single model, especially if `Student`s will not be using the platform regularly. Is there any problems with validating manually on the backend the identity of the `Student` and then setting a cookie in that session so the backend knows the session has been verified?

Comment: @colioli you can create a separate model with your required fields. You said teacher will submit this data and unique code for each student. so whenever student access provided links all you have to do is prepare a form which takes 2 inputs unique code and bdate. that form submission will trigger a function and validates those data based on that returns related response.  This implementation will make data disappear from UI once page is refreshed. but that can be handled too.